# Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Well, I have an issue with creating vpcs, sgs and rds-db and ec2 instances. The error says that I have a DB instance and EC2 security group in different VPCs. But, do I? I assigned sgs in one vpc and I still do not understand why I got this error. Can somebody explain it to me?

```
resource "aws_vpc" "mainvpc" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

#Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet-1" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.0.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone       = "us-east-2a"

  tags      = {
    Name    = "Public Subnet 1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet-1" {
  vpc_id                   = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  cidr_block               = "10.0.2.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch  = false
  availability_zone        = "us-east-2b"

  tags      = {
    Name    = "Private Subnet 1"
  }
}
```

Here is a sgs I've created and assigned it to vpc mainvpc

```
# Security Group
resource "aws_security_group" "wp" {
  name        = "WP-sg"
  description = "Allow SSH and HTTP inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "SSH traffic"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    self        = true
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {  
    description = "HTTP traffic"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    self        = true
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {  
    description = "Ping"
    protocol    = "icmp"
    self        = true
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "SG for WordPress"
  }

}

resource "aws_security_group" "db" {
  description = "Allow WordPress inbound traffic"
vpc_id = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "Wordpress traffic"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    self        = true
    from_port   = 3306
    to_port     = 3306

  }

 
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_security_group.wp]

  tags = {
    Name = "SG for Mysql"
  }
}


#DB
resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
    allocated_storage        = 15
    max_allocated_storage    = 100
    engine                   = "mysql"
    engine_version           = "5.7"
    instance_class           = "db.t2.micro"
    name                     = "dbwp"
    username                 = "---"
    password                 = "---"
    parameter_group_name     = "default.mysql5.7"
    skip_final_snapshot      = true
    vpc_security_group_ids   = [aws_security_group.db.id]
}

# EC2
resource "aws_instance" "app_yi" {
    ami           = "---"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.wp.id]
    depends_on = [aws_db_instance.db]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The error says that I have a DB instance and EC2 security group in different VPCs. But, do I?

Yes, both the database and the EC2 instance are in the `default` VPC, not in your `mainvpc` which you create.

For the EC2 instance in order to be in the same VPC as your security groups, you either have to specify the `subnet_id` or you have to create a `aws_network_interface` which will require a `subnet_id`.

For the database, you will have to create a [`aws_db_subnet_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_subnet_group) and specify the subnet group name for `db_subnet_group_name` on the `aws_db_instance` resource.